# Criação de um app de comunicação

Tags: android, web-service

Boa noite galera, estou planejando desenvolver um app de comunicação estilo whatsapp, mais na intenção de aprender mesmo, nada mais que isso. Bom, o app irá ter lista de contatos | conversas | solicitacões pendentes.

Nessa pergunta irei apenas me referir ao contatos, como será que e feito essa interação com outros usuários lhe solicitando um pedido de amizade.

Imaginei da seguinte forma, vou ter na minha aplicação um service que fica escutando um webservice (esse webservice retornaria um objeto quando existisse no bando de dados a solicitação), ai quando existisse resposta do webservice ele gravaria em um XML os contatos pendentes e excluiria da tabela, depois executaria um *broadcast* com uma notificação no celular com os dados do objeto que estaria na *intent*.

Bom, sei que deve ser alguma bibliotecas que faz essa troca de informação, mas parece que eu sempre estou fazendo algo muito ruim, pois no webservice estaria executando uma *query* pra dar de resposta.

Gostaria de saber se alguém tem ideia de como e feito nesses app populares, ou se deveria usar *sockets* ao invés de webservice. Obrigado.

Comment: Eu sei que tem uns que são WebApps que usam basicamente ajax pra tudo, mas pra os que não são feitos de web, acho que a melhor opção são os sockets...

Answer (score 1):

Neste caso, eu particularmente, recomendo uso de um banco de dados NoSQL no lado Server pra atuar com uma performance minimamente aceitável (MongoDB).

Sobre sua pergunta, o WhatsApp por exemplo utiliza um conceito chamado SSL Socket (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html), não é um tema tão trivial, então você vai ter que estudar com paciência o funcionamento dele se quiser implementar.

nesse link:

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/43970/how-is-whatsapp-able-to-receive-messages-when-not-in-use

tem uma resposta bem legal (a primeira senão me engano) sobre a dinamica "app -> servidor" x "servidor -> app" para o funcionamento dos sockets...

lembrando que o lado server do whatsapp é feito em earlang, mas pra começar você pode estudar esse projeto feito em PHP disponível no GitHub:

https://github.com/venomous0x/WhatsAPI

Pelo menos pra começar é bom, pra captar os conceitos..

Comment: Nossa, muito bom não imaginei que iria receber uma resposta assim tão detalhada, obrigado mesmo. É uma pena que esses tópicos dentro da programação que eu chamo de ('AVANÇADO') não são abordadas em faculdades e nos cursos disponiveis na internet..muito obrigado novamente.

Comment: :), precisando é só postar aí..